# How to pass multiple optional parameter in mobx-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

In react router we can pass optional parameters '/:param1?/:param2?'. But when i am trying to pass multiple parameters(as in following example '/home/:action?/:code?') in mobx-routers, it is not loading my component. However, it is working fine with single parameter i.e. '/home/:action?'

Here is sample code..

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'mobx-router'
const LazyRoute = ({ Component, ...props }) => <Component {...props} />

const routes = {
  home: new Route({
    path: '/home/:action?/:code?',
    component: <LazyRoute Component={lazy(() => import('../home'))} router={router} />,
  }),
}

export default routes
```